# What type of connector is this (see picture)?

Tags: connector, identification

I could not find out what type of connector this is. It has a width of approximately 10mm, 0.5mm pitch, and 30 pins. I assume it is some kind of diagnostic port. It is part of a mobile device with OMAP4470 processor. Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: What device is this connected to? (please edit your question with these details)

Comment: Connectors ate usually classified by pitch (distance between two pins). This information would be more relevant than the total width.

Comment: It looks like a custom JST connector with 30 dual row centre contacts and 30 dual row side contacts perhaps for high speed interleaved grounds.

Comment: There are a lot of similar-looking connectors. Measure the pitch (use a number of pins and divide by the number of spaces) and look at things like so-called mezzanine connectors.

Comment: I might have found it: https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/h/hirose/df12-series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at JST part [30R-JMCS-G-B-TF(NSA)](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/30R-JMCS-G-B-TF-NSA/455-2852CT-ND/3790033)
Mezzanine Connector  Pitch matches.

[image]